# What does %2.6f do in Objective C String Formatting?

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting

Based on Apple's documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

It's pretty easy to understand the number to the right of the decimal point is the number of digis will be rounded up...

For example, %1.2f, 123456.123456 will turn out 123456.12 and %1.4f will turn out 123456.1234...

But it looks like the number to the left of decimal does nothing.

I tried changing the number to whatever I can think of, nothing happened.

What does it do?

Comment: Try %10.2f and you will see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number before the decimal point in the format is called the format string's *width*. That is, if the resultant string would involves less characters than its width, it will be left-padded with blank spaces.  You don't see any change because you either aren't using a high enough number (try something ridiculous like 100 or 200), or don't have a means of properly seeing your whitespace.